# Raspberry Pi 4 becomes unresponsive after Chromium idle

Tags: kernel, pi-4, chromium, raspbian-buster, lightdm

I am building a kiosk application on my Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB RAM Version) that requires that Chromium continuously idles as a service. I created a supervisorctl service that will keep it alive and give me the ability to easily stop, start, fetch status, etc.

However, after some time I am noticing that the entire interface freezes. I had Chromium running in the background and 3 terminals in the foreground:

1. Terminal running `tail -f` of the service log
2. Terminal running `dmesg -w`
3. Terminal running `htop`

After my Pi idled for about 3 hours, sure enough the interface froze. The Pi was functional from an SSH perspective, I could run commands and do whatever I wanted but there was a severe crash from the interface side.

Looking at the terminals I had open for more information, here is what I got:

1. Terminal 1 provided no information.
2. Terminal 2 provided some information:

```
[ 8845.340649]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8845.340653] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8845.340658] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 8845.340680] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 8845.340698] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8845.340707] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 8845.340715] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 8845.340723] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 8845.340732] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 8845.340741] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8845.340747] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8845.340756] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 8845.340765] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 8845.340773] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 8845.340780] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 8845.340788] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 8845.340797] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8845.340805] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8845.340812] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8845.340819] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8845.340824] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 8845.340829] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340834] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340839] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 8845.340845] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 8845.340849]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8845.340853] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8845.340857] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 8845.340873] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 8845.340885] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8845.340892] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 8845.340901] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 8845.340909] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 8845.340916] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 8845.340924] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 8845.340930] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8845.340937] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8845.340945] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 8845.340960] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8845.340967] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8845.340973] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8845.340979] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8845.340983] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 8845.340988] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340993] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8845.340998] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 8968.221452] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 8968.221459]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8968.221463] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8968.221468] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 8968.221490] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 8968.221513] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8968.221522] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 8968.221531] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 8968.221539] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 8968.221547] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 8968.221557] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8968.221564] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8968.221572] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 8968.221581] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 8968.221589] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 8968.221597] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 8968.221604] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 8968.221614] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8968.221623] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8968.221629] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8968.221637] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8968.221642] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 8968.221647] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221652] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221657] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 8968.221663] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 8968.221668]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 8968.221671] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8968.221675] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 8968.221692] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 8968.221704] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 8968.221712] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 8968.221720] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 8968.221728] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 8968.221736] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 8968.221743] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 8968.221750] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 8968.221757] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 8968.221765] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 8968.221775] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 8968.221782] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 8968.221788] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 8968.221794] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 8968.221798] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 8968.221803] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221808] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 8968.221816] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9091.102268] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9091.102275]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9091.102279] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9091.102284] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 9091.102305] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 9091.102322] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9091.102330] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 9091.102339] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 9091.102347] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 9091.102356] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 9091.102364] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9091.102371] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9091.102379] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 9091.102387] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 9091.102395] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 9091.102403] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 9091.102411] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 9091.102420] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9091.102428] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9091.102435] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9091.102443] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9091.102447] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 9091.102452] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102458] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102463] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9091.102469] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9091.102473]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9091.102476] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9091.102480] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 9091.102497] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 9091.102508] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9091.102516] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 9091.102524] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 9091.102532] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 9091.102540] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 9091.102547] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 9091.102554] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9091.102561] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9091.102569] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 9091.102578] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9091.102585] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9091.102591] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9091.102597] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9091.102602] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 9091.102606] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102612] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9091.102616] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9213.983078] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9213.983085]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9213.983089] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9213.983094] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 9213.983115] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 9213.983133] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9213.983141] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 9213.983150] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 9213.983157] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 9213.983166] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 9213.983174] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9213.983181] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9213.983190] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 9213.983199] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 9213.983207] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 9213.983215] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 9213.983222] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 9213.983232] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9213.983240] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9213.983247] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9213.983254] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9213.983259] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 9213.983264] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983270] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983274] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9213.983280] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9213.983285]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9213.983288] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9213.983292] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 9213.983309] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 9213.983320] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9213.983328] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 9213.983336] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 9213.983344] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 9213.983351] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 9213.983359] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 9213.983366] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9213.983373] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9213.983381] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 9213.983390] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9213.983397] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9213.983404] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9213.983410] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9213.983414] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 9213.983419] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983424] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9213.983429] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9336.863894] INFO: task kworker/2:0:13859 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9336.863900]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9336.863904] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9336.863909] kworker/2:0     D    0 13859      2 0x00000000
[ 9336.863931] Workqueue: events dbs_work_handler
[ 9336.863947] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9336.863956] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout+0x200/0x428)
[ 9336.863964] [<c099ba7c>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common+0xd4/0x1b0)
[ 9336.863972] [<c0998704>] (wait_for_common) from [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion+0x20/0x24)
[ 9336.863981] [<c0998800>] (wait_for_completion) from [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x78/0xd0)
[ 9336.863989] [<c08109f4>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9336.863996] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9336.864015] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1+0x58/0x80)
[ 9336.864023] [<c07e7e74>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_clock_property.constprop.1) from [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index+0x5c/0xe4)
[ 9336.864031] [<c07e7ef8>] (bcm2835_cpufreq_driver_target_index) from [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target+0x2d8/0x5a8)
[ 9336.864038] [<c07e2b54>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update+0xec/0x174)
[ 9336.864046] [<c07e65a0>] (od_dbs_update) from [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler+0x3c/0x68)
[ 9336.864055] [<c07e71bc>] (dbs_work_handler) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9336.864064] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9336.864070] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9336.864077] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9336.864082] Exception stack(0xd731dfb0 to 0xd731dff8)
[ 9336.864087] dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864092] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864097] dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[ 9336.864103] INFO: task kworker/3:2:14075 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 9336.864107]       Tainted: G         C        4.19.75-v7l+ #1270
[ 9336.864111] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 9336.864115] kworker/3:2     D    0 14075      2 0x00000000
[ 9336.864132] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[ 9336.864143] [<c0997424>] (__schedule) from [<c0997a94>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[ 9336.864151] [<c0997a94>] (schedule) from [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x1c)
[ 9336.864159] [<c0997ef0>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5+0x1a8/0x590)
[ 9336.864166] [<c0998fa0>] (__mutex_lock.constprop.5) from [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath+0x1c/0x20)
[ 9336.864174] [<c09994a4>] (__mutex_lock_slowpath) from [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock+0x5c/0x60)
[ 9336.864182] [<c0999504>] (mutex_lock) from [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction+0x54/0xd0)
[ 9336.864188] [<c08109d0>] (rpi_firmware_transaction) from [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x140/0x2b0)
[ 9336.864195] [<c0810b8c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x7c/0xfc)
[ 9336.864203] [<c0810d78>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll+0x4c/0x15c [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[ 9336.864213] [<bf1140c0>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c023db40>] (process_one_work+0x170/0x458)
[ 9336.864220] [<c023db40>] (process_one_work) from [<c023de84>] (worker_thread+0x5c/0x5a4)
[ 9336.864226] [<c023de84>] (worker_thread) from [<c0244170>] (kthread+0x138/0x168)
[ 9336.864232] [<c0244170>] (kthread) from [<c02010ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
[ 9336.864237] Exception stack(0xd7109fb0 to 0xd7109ff8)
[ 9336.864241] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864247] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 9336.864252] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
```

3. Terminal 3 appeared to show a healthy device:
   [htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lduj3.png)

Additionally, I tried to do a `sudo service lightdm restart`, but the terminal just hung and did not do anything. See sys-log below:

```
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Killing process 576 (lightdm) with signal SIGKILL.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Killing process 702 (Xorg) with signal SIGKILL.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1232 (openbox) with signal SIGKILL.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 16 15:24:30 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user pi.
```

After this failed, I did a `sudo reboot now` and the system never rebooted. I had to unplug and plug the device back in.

Can someone help me figure out what is going on here? What could be causing this issue?

For your reference, please see output of os-release below:

```
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Comment: I've had several chromium applications with a memory leak. Eventually saturating the RAM and making the system unresponsive.

Comment: Rpi Chromium and BlueTooth are my sorrows since Rpi1. I hope no more sorrows after Rpi7.

Comment: @Botspot the weird thing is, the RAM looks fine on the htop

Comment: have the same issue, please let us know if you find any solution for this issue.